# What is a computationally efficient way to generate a list of a large number of combinations with certain restraints?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

We have a set of objects indexed by integers and need to generate a list of pairs of possible combinations  of these objects (of any length up to the number of objects) with a constraint. The constraint is that if one combination in a pair contains an object, then the other combination in that pair cannot also contain that object.

As an example, if we have only 3 objects { 0, 1, 2}, the list should look like

```
{ {0}, {1} }
{ {0}, {2} }
{ {1}, {2} }
{ {0,1}, {2} }
{ {0}, {1,2} }
{ {0,2}, {1} }
```

What is a computationally efficient way of generating this list for as many as 20 objects in C++?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "millions of sets". All sets of, say, 10 objects will have the exact same solution - you can compute it once. The only variable here is `N`, the number of objects.

Comment: Use a flat `std::vector` instead of a "set". Each time you pick, or randomly remove an object from the vector, replace it with the last object in the vector and decrement the size of the vector by one (unless you picked the last object in the vector, in which case you just decrement). In this manner you will never "pick" the same object. And how to arrange the randomly picked objects (one at a time) into your pairs should is a very simple homework assignment.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The millions of sets will be an issue for how we use the list, but not for actually generating the list. That is a silly oversight on my part. However, the issue of generating such a list remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we can decide which element will be in our pairs.
For example, if the number of element is 3, consider the binary representation from 0 to 2^3.

```
0=000
1=001
2=010
3=011
4=100
5=101
6=110
7=111
```

Now, we will make the pair from each number from 0 to 2^n by  keeping the elements in which position the number has 1. Like 3=011, its first and second position have 1, so we will make a pair with first and second element.For 6=110,we will make the pair with second and third element.
So, we can decide which element we will take in our each pair through 2^n complexity, where n is the number of element.

Now we know which element will be in each pair.
For example, let for one pair we selected m elements. Now we need to divide them within each side. We can do it like the similar way by considering binary representation of all numbers from m elements.
If m=3,

```
    0=000
    1=001
    2=010
    3=011
    4=100
    5=101
    6=110
    7=111
```

So from each number from 0 to 2^m, we  can make a pair. For making a pair from a number , we will keep the elements in first set which index has 0 in that number and will keep in the second set which index has 1 in that number.
C++ code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    long long  cnt=0;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int object[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)cin>>object[i];

    for(int i=0; i<(1<<n); i++){
        // From each i, we will decide which element will be in our set.
        int c=0;
        int nu=0;
        int one_pair[n];
        // Now we will calculate , how many elements will be in current pair.
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)if((i&(1<<j)))one_pair[c++]=object[j];
        if(c>=2){
            // So we have c element in each pair 
            for(int k=1; k<(1<<(c-1)); k++){
                //Now we will divide each of the c element within two sides.
                cout<<"{ {";
                bool fl=0;
                for(int divider=0;divider<c;divider++){
                   if((k&(1<<divider))){
                        if(fl)cout<<",";
                        fl=1;
                        cout<<one_pair[divider];
                   }
                }

                cout<<"}, ";
                cout<<"{";
                fl=0;
                for(int divider=0;divider<c;divider++){
                   if((k&(1<<divider))==0){
                        if(fl)cout<<",";
                        fl=1;
                        cout<<one_pair[divider];
                   }
                }
                cout<<"} }"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  3
0 1 2
{ {0}, {1} }
{ {0}, {2} }
{ {1}, {2} }
{ {0}, {1,2} }
{ {1}, {0,2} }
{ {0,1}, {2} }
```

Answer (score 4):

In each pair, every object is either not used, or it's in the left set, or it's in the right set.

If you have N objects, you can easily iterate through the 3^N possibilities, skipping the ones that result in empty sets:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned N = 5; //number of objects
    vector<unsigned> left, right;

    for (unsigned index=0 ;; ++index) {
        left.clear();
        right.clear();

        //treat the index as a number in base 3
        //each digit determines the fate of one object
        unsigned digits=index;
        for (int obj=1; obj<=N; ++obj) {
            unsigned pos=digits%3;
            digits /= 3;
            if (pos == 1)
                left.push_back(obj);
            else if (pos == 2)
                right.push_back(obj);
        }

        if (digits) {
            //done all possibilities
            break;
        }

        if (left.empty() || right.empty()) {
            // don't want empty left or right
            continue;
        }

        //got one -- print it
        cout << "{ {" <<left[0];
        for (size_t i=1; i<left.size(); ++i)
            cout << "," << left[i];
        cout << "}, {" <<right[0];
        for (size_t i=1; i<right.size(); ++i)
            cout << "," << right[i];
        cout << "} }" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If `unsigned` is 32 bits, this will work for up to 20 objects.  Note that it will print about 3.5 *billion* pairs in that case, though.

Try it here: https://ideone.com/KIeas7

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive version that takes each combination in the powerset with more than one element and runs a "put in one bag or the other" routine. (It's pretty much my first time trying to code anything more than trivial in C++ so I imagine there may be room for improvement.)

```
Powerset:
{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0}, {1, 2}, {1}, {2}, {}}

{{0, 1}, {2}}
{{0, 2}, {1}}
{{0}, {1, 2}}

{{0}, {1}}

{{0}, {2}}

{{1}, {2}}
```

Code (also [here](https://ideone.com/NuXHf4)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print(std::vector<int> const &input){
      std::cout << '{';
      for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << input.at(i);
        if (i < input.size() - 1)
          std::cout << ", ";
      }
      std::cout << '}';
}
void printMany(std::vector< std::vector<int> > const &input)
{
    std::cout << '{';
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
      print(input.at(i));
      if (i < input.size() - 1)
        std::cout << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '}';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
void printPairs(std::vector< std::vector<int> > const &input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i+=2) {
      cout << '{';
      print(input.at(i));
      cout << ", ";
      print(input.at(i + 1));
      cout << "}\n";
    }
}

std::vector< std::vector<int> > f(std::vector<int> const &A, int i, const std::vector<int> &left, const std::vector<int> &right) {
  if (i == A.size() - 1 && right.empty())
    return std::vector< std::vector<int> >{left, std::vector<int> {A[i]}};
  if (i == A.size())
    return std::vector< std::vector<int> > {left, right};

  std::vector<int> _left{ left };
  _left.emplace_back(A[i]);
  std::vector< std::vector<int> > result = f(A, i + 1, _left, right);
  std::vector<int> _right{ right };
  _right.emplace_back(A[i]);
  std::vector< std::vector<int> > result1 = f(A, i + 1, left, _right);
  result.insert( result.end(), result1.begin(), result1.end() );
  return result;
}

std::vector< std::vector<int> > powerset(std::vector<int> const &A, const vector<int>& prefix = vector<int>(), int i = 0) {
  if (i == A.size())
    return std::vector< std::vector<int> > {prefix};

  std::vector<int> _prefix(prefix);
  _prefix.emplace_back(A[i]);
  std::vector< std::vector<int> > result = powerset(A, _prefix, i + 1);
  std::vector< std::vector<int> > result1 = powerset(A, prefix, i + 1);
  result.insert( result.end(), result1.begin(), result1.end() );
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> A{0, 1, 2};
  std::vector< std::vector<int> > ps = powerset(A);
  cout << "Powerset:\n";
  printMany(ps);
  cout << "\nResult:\n";
  for (int i=0; i<ps.size(); i++){
    if (ps.at(i).size() > 1){
      std::vector<int> left{ps.at(i)[0]};
      std::vector<int> right;
      printPairs(f(ps.at(i), 1, left, right));
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```